# When do I need to use state management? (Angular, React, Vue)

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js, frontend

I am a junior frontend developer. My company is a small company, and started to use Angular for a couple of months. Including me, our frontend apps is written by two people.

So this is a general frontend framework question, really. When do you actually realize that your apps need to use a state management library??? Is it bad to write your business logic inside the component??

This is an Angular specific question: Because Angular have DI, why use 3rd-party redux-like central store (NGRx, NGXs) rather than observable service per module???

Comment: I suggest reading this article: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/the-art-of-the-state-e19816732530

Answer (score 1):

I have been writing Angular apps for a few years and I never found a reason to use NGRX or a state management Library. Angular is pretty complex starting out, so my recommendation is to start small. When you need to use a state management library, you will know it!

The Observable Data Pattern works well for the most part, but there is a point where your project could get large and the amount of these services could get really confusing. At that point, maybe you would consider a state management library. Just my opinion, but I havent worked on a project that large where Observable Data Services wasn't sufficient enough.

I normally do not write business logic in Javascript. I have been using a server technology for that. If you do write business logic, I would put them all in services where they are easily reusable and testable. This can encourage pure functions as well, which can help you avoid state hell. Just things I ran into starting out. Writing test cases will help since you will get better with Angular and may want to refactor things later. Having test you can run can give you confidence nothing broke.

Good luck!

Angular Style guide has some good guidelines:
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: waiting for things to blow up before planning for a solution is a not a good approach on this profession. Do your mistakes. use NGRX on small apps. do it again. and then again. by the 3rd app you'll figure out when you need to use it and when not to. congrads, you now have an extra tool in your toolbox.

Comment: I dont think NGRX everything is a good solution either. I don't believe in making a project more complicated than it needs to be for both time and maintenance purposes. Other developers may need to work on this and now they have to learn a complicated design pattern on a small app.(Just an example). Observable Data Services is a viable option for State Management. I edited my answer for a bit more clarity, but you should be using NGRX if you have a good reason to do it, not just because its a hot topic. There are a lot of options for state management

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services), your business logic should live in services, while components should only take care of UI related logic.

> Services are a great way to share information among classes that don't know each other

In Angular is not suggested to write your business logic into components. All components have their own state, which describe the UI they implement.

That being said:

> When do I need to use state management?

In general you will see that as your app grows it will be harder to keep track of events and data changes, how you fetch data, where errors are handled, how you cache data. It will quickly become hard to foresee how your application behave under certain conditions.

There is a clear need to coordinate all the actors in your application (UI, backend, web workers..), which update the state concurrently.

State management is about designing a clear specification of how these actors interact with one another and the shared/local state.